# Combinatorics , choose 5 numbers out of positive and negative numbers

Tags: combinatorics

Following numbers are given: $-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,1,2,3,4,5,6$

In how many ways can you choose $5$ numbers of the numbers above, if the product of these are suppost to be positive.

a) Repetition is not allowed

b) Repetition is allowed

For a) and b) order does not matter.

c) What is the answer in a) if it is important in wich order the numbers are choosen?

My attempt:
a) We need to have $0,2 $ or $4$ negative numbers if the product is suppost to be positive. I have $8$ negative numbers and $6$ positive. Order does not matter here so it should be:
$C(8,0)\times C(6,5) + C(8,2) \times C(6,3) + C(8,4) \times C(6,1)$

b) Repetition is allowed and order does not matter.

Case 1: There are 0 negative numbers and 5 positive. If $x_i$ =The amount of a postive number, $i$ is between 1 and 6, and $x_i$ is equal or larger then zero. Then I get $x_1+x_2+x_3+...+ x_6 = 5$ , wich will give me $C(10,5)$ ways

Case 2: There are 2 negative numbers and 3 postive. If $Z_i = $ The amout of $A$ negative number, i is between 1 and 8. Then I get $z_1+z_2+...+ z_8 = 2$ and $x_1+x_2+...+x_6= 3$. This gives me $C(9,2) \times C(8,3)$

Case 3: There are 4 negative numbers and 1 positive. Then I get $z1+z2+...+z8 = 4$ and $x1+x2+...+x6 =1$. This gives me $C(11,4) \times C(6,1)$

The sum= $4248$

c) Order is important and repitition is not allowed.

Case 1: 5 postive, 0 negative
$P(6,5) = 720$

Case 2: 2 negative, 3 positive
$C(5,2) \times P(8,2) \times P(6,3) = 67200$

Case 3: 4 negative, 1 positive
$C(5,4) \times P(8,4) \times P(6,1) = 50400$

Total =$118320. $

Am I correct on a), b) and c)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your answers are correct. For part (c), you may want to just use your answer from part $a$ -

$\displaystyle {8 \choose 0} {6 \choose 5} + {8 \choose 2} {6 \choose 3} + {8 \choose 4} {6 \choose 1} = 986$

Now once you have the $5$ numbers you can arrange them in $5!$ ways as order matters for part (c).

So, total number of ways for part (c) $ = 986 \times 5! = 118320$ which is same as your answer.